# Integrate Google API's Analytics Client Library PHP into Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, google-api-php-client

I have successfully followed through the following Google article, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php and setup a basic php script for extracting Analytics data. It was quite easy :-)

I am now trying to integrate this code into my Symfony2 project. Now it seems that the library is written in an ancient style, no namespacing and filenames are different to that of the class in them. Can anyone help me on how I can integrate it into my symfony project? I have loaded in the git repository via composer with the follwoing:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "google/google-api-php-client",
                "version": "1.1.4",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/archive/1.1.4.zip",
                    "type": "zip",
                    "reference": "1.1.4"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

But the issue is all of the autoloading etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library has a [`composer.json`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/composer.json) file and is registered in [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient), so you just need to add `"google/apiclient": "1.1.4"` in your composer's require section, and composer will handle the autoloading.

Then to integrate it to Symfony the right way, please read the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) to learn how to register your own services in your `services.yml` file.

Define your application name and your key as parameters in your `parameters.yml` to reuse them in your service definitions.

Define a service for each class you instanciate (e.g. a service for `Google_Client`, `Google_Service_Analytics`, `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials`, ...) with the right dependencies on other services and/or parameters.

Note: I've found those bundle on [knpbundles](http://knpbundles.com/): [isometriks/GoogleApiBundle](https://github.com/isometriks/GoogleApiBundle) and [Happyr/GoogleApiBundle](https://github.com/Happyr/GoogleApiBundle), they may help.

Comment: Thanks very much, worked a treat! :-) How silly of me to not look for a packagist package!